# Python XML ElementTree not reading node with &

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML, with one of the nodes having '&' within a string:

```
<uid>JAMES&001</uid>
```

now, when I try to read the whole xml using the following code:

```
tree = et.parse(fileName)
root = tree.getroot()
ids = root.findall("uid")
```

I get the error on the link of the above-mentioned node:

```
xml.etree.ElelmentTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line17, column 21
```

The code works fine on other instances where there is no '&'. I guess it's breaking the string.

Can it be fixed with encoding? How? I searched through other questions but couldn't find an answer.

TIA

Comment: No, you don't have an XML. You have a not-XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sanitize your xml first since it isn't well formed.

You need to replace the offending `&` - something like `.replace("&", "&amp;")`

One way to use it:

```
with open(fileName, 'r+') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        doc = ET.fromstring(read_data.replace("&", "&amp;"))
        print(doc.find('./uid').text)
```

Output, given your sample, should be

```
JAMES&001
```